# Valgrind ==10731== invalid write of size 8

Tags: c, valgrind

Here is my code:

```
struct FileNode {
    char *filename;
    double tf;
    struct FileNode *next;
};

typedef struct FileNode *FileList;

FileList newFileList(){
    FileList fl = malloc(sizeof(FileList));
    fl->next = NULL;
    fl->tf = 0.0;

    return fl;
}
```

Here is my valgrind output.

```
==10731== Invalid write of size 8
==10731==    at 0x1097B7: newFileList (invertedIndex.c:73)
==10731==    by 0x109852: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:89)
==10731==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==10731==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)
==10731==  Address 0x4bd10a0 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10731==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==10731==    by 0x1097AE: newFileList (invertedIndex.c:72)
==10731==    by 0x109852: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:89)
==10731==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==10731==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)
==10731== 
==10731== Invalid write of size 8
==10731==    at 0x1097C7: newFileList (invertedIndex.c:74)
==10731==    by 0x109852: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:89)
==10731==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==10731==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)
==10731==  Address 0x4bd1098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10731==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==10731==    by 0x1097AE: newFileList (invertedIndex.c:72)
==10731==    by 0x109852: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:89)
==10731==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==10731==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)
```

I don't know why it is causing this. I am putting in a double and it says invalid write of size 8.
The same with fl->next = NULL

Comment: And now you know why we normally avoid creating typedefs for pointers. It's too confusing/unexpected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use :

```c
FileList fl = malloc(sizeof(struct FileNode));
```

Because `sizeof(FileList)` only allocates `8 bytes` & you're trying write beyond 8 bytes. On the other hand `sizeof(struct FileNode)` allocates space for all the members of `struct FileNode` which is your intention, so that later you can store desired values.

With a simple debug print (or using a debugger), you can find out the size differences.

2. `fNodePtr_t` may be an apt name instead of `FileList`.

```c
typedef struct FileNode* fNodePtr_t;
```

3. It's safer to check the return value of `malloc()` call:

```c
fNodePtr_t newFileList(){
    fNodePtr_t fl = malloc(sizeof(struct FileNode));
    if (NULL == fl) {
        perror ("newFileList");
        return NULL;
    }
    fl->next = NULL;
    fl->tf = 0.0;

    return fl;
}
```

Comment: This is for my uni assignment so I can't change the name and if Filelist is a pointer to FileNode (FileNode *) why does using a struct FileNode work? Also why am I trying to write more than 8 bytes? Is it for the properties?